# consulta que recupere los datos correspondientes a la ultima version, de cada uno de los ID de la tabla

Tags: mysql

Mi intención es crear una consulta que me entregue los datos correspondientes a la última versión de cada ID (`tipobase`)

| tipoBase | Tipsop | Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | irres | 1 |
| a | restr | 1 |
| b | irres | 2 |
| b | irres | 3 |

Donde el ID será el tipoBase que mes a mes aumenta y en *version* pueden existir x cantidad de versiones

La tabla se llama **tabla_1**

```
select * from tabla_1 where select max(version) version from tabla_1
```

Pero para cada tipoBase.

Para explicarlo más claro cada *TipoBase* podría tener varias versiones, necesito traer la última versión

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar este problema debes agrupar por `tipoBase,tipoSop` en un `GROUP BY` y lo tendrás solucionado.

```
SELECT MAX(version),tipoBase,tipoSop FROM tabla1 GROUP BY tipoBase,tipoSop;
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/403)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes apoyarte en la cláusula `group by` y pasarle el `tipoBase` como campo de agrupación

```
select max(version) version, tipoBase, Tipsop
from tabla_1
group by tipoBase
```

Comment: Esto en mysql 8 no va a funcionar, el group by esta incompleto... aunque la respuesta es por este lado...